# Elevation profiles of OSM street paths

Tags: openstreetmap

Elevation data isn't integrated into OSM streets directly, but both OSM street paths and elevation resources are separately available.

My objective is to find the largest hills on roads in any given area. What is the best set of tools and elevation data available to do this? Has something like this been done before? I'm coming from an R/C++ and JavaScript background.

Comment: I would go for SRTM data to start with and possibly use PostgreSQL + PostGIS to map the elevation to the road network.

Comment: If you can be more specific than "any given area" then it would help to narrow down some elevation data. Global elevation data will be too coarse in most places to give you sensible results, when mapped to road vectors (e.g. 30m-100m resolution).

Comment: @alphabetasoup Thanks! Ideally I'm looking at all populated areas in US, Canada and Europe, so it may be a smorgasbord of national databases?

Comment: https://opentopography.org/ may be the answer, though I can't vouch for it